# Converting Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image to bytes for SQL storage

Tags: c#, maui

HEllo I have been using camera.Maui API's and they are very nice, however I need to be able to convert the image to bytes for storage.

I have tried a number of methods streaming, memory streaming, convertors.

Here is the conversion attempt, that gives the closest results but with the error can't convert Microsoft.maui.controls.image to system.byte[]

```
public static byte[] converterDemo(Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image x)
{
   ImageFormatConverter _imageConverter = new ImageFormatConverter();
   byte[] xByte = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(x, typeof(byte[]));
   return xByte;
}
```

Here is the image capture.

```
 void Photo_Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Image1.Source == null)
        {
            Image1.Source = cameraView.GetSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG);
            Image1asBytes = ImageConverter.converterDemo(Image1);
        }
        else if (Image2.Source == null)
        {
            Image2.Source = cameraView.GetSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG);
            Image2asBytes = ImageConverter.converterDemo(Image2);
        }

        else if (Image3.Source == null)
        {
            Image3.Source = cameraView.GetSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG);
            Image3asBytes = ImageConverter.converterDemo(Image3);
        }

        else if (Image4.Source == null)
        {
            Image4.Source = cameraView.GetSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG);
            Image4asBytes = ImageConverter.converterDemo(Image4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `ImageFormatConverter` from? Couldn't find it in a quick search. Given it exists and _would_ work, you are probably not giving it the correct input type. I suspect you need to give it the ImageSource ( `.Source` property), not the `Image` Control itself? (Maybe)

Comment: Have you tried using the SnapshotStream property?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried image source it also returns an exception.

Comment: here is the link to the image converter class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageconverter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: that converter is for `System.Drawing.Image` objects, not MAUI `Image` controls.  You need to capture the bytes as they're returned from the camera.  You can try the `SnapshotStream` property I mentioned earlier, or using the `SaveSnapshot` to save to disk and then read the `byte[]` from the file.  There may be other properties/methods that would work, I didn't exhaustively look at all of them